# Contrasting covariance calculation using R, Matlab, Pandas, NumPy cov, NumPy linalg.svd

Tags: r, matlab, covariance, scikit-learn, svd

I wish there were a kind of Rosetta Stone for covariance (and other) stat methods supplied by popular statistics libraries and software, so that we could understand why what is ostensibly the same method gives different results in different libraries. I am aware that most of the discrepancies are due to scaling and normalizing factors, but these factors are usually not explained in the documentation sets of these libraries, and some of the discrepancies are pretty significant. If approaches to normalization and scaling are widely understood, why is it so difficult to write Python code that manually reproduces the output of these methods? Shouldn't the algorithms used in these popular libraries be more transparent?

**Test example 1**.

Input matrix A = $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

1. Output of cov(A) in R: $\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2 \\
   2 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}$
2. Output in R when input is $A^\top$: $\begin{pmatrix}
   0.5 & 0.5 \\
   0.5 & 0.5
   \end{pmatrix}$
3. Output of `cov(A)` in Matlab: $\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2 \\
   2 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}$
4. Output in Pandas: $\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2 \\
   2 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}$
5. Output in SciKit Learn Empirical Covariance: $\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}$
   *What sort of normalization or scaling is SciKit doing here?*
6. Output in NumPy using np.cov(): $\begin{pmatrix}
   0.5 & 0.5 \\
   0.5 & 0.5
   \end{pmatrix}$
7. Output from Python code that supposedly reflects what `np.cov()` is doing (according to [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062804/numpy-cov-covariance-function-what-exactly-does-it-compute)): $\begin{pmatrix}
   +2 & -2 \\
   -2 & +2
   \end{pmatrix}$
   *NOTE the sign difference in the off-diagonal elements!*
8. Output in NumPy using `np.linalg.svd()` to calculate covariance: $\begin{pmatrix}
   10 & -14 \\
   -14 & 20
   \end{pmatrix}$
   *The values here differ from Matlab by more than a constant factor or a square.*

**Code used to generate input matrices for Test 1**:

1. R code for A = matrix(
   + c(1, 3, 2, 4),
   + nrow=2,
   + ncol=2)
2. R code for input of `A.transpose = matrix(+ c(1, 2, 3, 4), + nrow=2, + ncol=2)`
3. Matlab code for input A = [1, 2; 3, 4]
4. Panda code: `DataFrame.cov(np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4])))`
5. SciKit Learn empirical covariance code:

   ```
   X = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4]))
   fit = EmpiricalCovariance().fit(X)
   fit.covariance_
   ```
6. NumPy code using `np.cov()`:

   ```
   X = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4]))
   np.cov(X)
   ```
7. Python code that supposedly reflects what's happening in `np.cov()`:

   ```
   X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4])) 
   X = X0 - X0.mean(axis=0)
   N = X.shape[1]
   fact = float(N - 1)
   C = np.dot(X, X.T) / fact
   ```

*NOTE that putting the transpose X.T first instead of second in np.dot(X.T, X) gives the same result as Matlab and R without the negative signs in the off-diagonal elements, but this is supposed to be an **outer product**!! What is backwards about the NumPy conventions such that we need to put the transpose term first in order to get an outer product?*

8. NumPy code to obtain covariance using `np.linalg.svd()` according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479918/trying-to-check-cov-matrix-calculation-from-svd-using-numpy):

   ```
   X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4])) 
   U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(X0, full_matrices = 0)
   D = np.dot(np.dot(V,np.diag(s**2)),V.T)
   Dadjust = D / (X0.shape[0] - 1)
   print (Dadjust)
   ```

*Again, the values here differ from Matlab by more than a constant factor or a square. Can anyone help me unravel this?*

**Test example 2**.

Input matrix A = $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  2 \\
 3 &  4 \\
22 & 44
\end{pmatrix}$

1. Output of `cov(A)` in R: $\begin{pmatrix}
   134.3333 & 274.3333 \\
   274.3333 & 561.3333
   \end{pmatrix}$
2. Output in R when input is $A^\top$: $\begin{pmatrix}
    0.5 &  0.5 &  11 \\
    0.5 &  0.5 &  11 \\
   11.0 & 11.0 & 242
   \end{pmatrix}$
3. Output in Matlab: $\begin{pmatrix}
   134.3333 & 274.3333 \\
   274.3333 & 561.3333
   \end{pmatrix}$
4. Output in Pandas: $\begin{pmatrix}
   134.3333 & 274.3333 \\
   274.3333 & 561.3333
   \end{pmatrix}$
5. Output in SciKit Learn Empirical Covariance: $\begin{pmatrix}
   89.55555556 & 182.88888889 \\
   182.88888889 & 374.22222222
   \end{pmatrix}$
6. Output in NumPy using np.cov(): $\begin{pmatrix}
   0.5 & 0.5 & 11 \\
   0.5 & 0.5 & 11 \\
   11  & 11  & 242
   \end{pmatrix}$
7. Output from Python code that supposedly reflects what `np.cov()` is doing (according to [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062804/numpy-cov-covariance-function-what-exactly-does-it-compute)): $\begin{pmatrix}
   273.88888889 & 229.22222222 & -503.11111111 \\
   229.22222222 & 192.55555556 & -421.77777778 \\
   -503.11111111 & -421.77777778 & 924.88888889
   \end{pmatrix}$
8. Output in NumPy using np.linalg.svd() to calculate covariance:  $\begin{pmatrix}
   247 & 491 \\
   491 & 978
   \end{pmatrix}$

**Code used to generate input matrices for Test 2**:

1. R code for `A = matrix(+ c(1, 3, 22, 2, 4, 44), + nrow=3, + ncol=2)`
2. R code for covariance with input of $A^\top$:

   ```
   Atranspose = t(A)
   cov(Atranspose)
   ```
3. Matlab code for input A = [1, 2; 3, 4; 22, 44]
4. Panda code: `DataFrame.cov(np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44])))`
5. SciKit Learn empirical covariance code:

   ```
   X = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44])
   fit = EmpiricalCovariance().fit(X)
   fit.covariance_
   ```
6. NumPy code using `np.cov()`:

   ```
   X = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44])
   np.cov(X)
   ```
7. Python code that supposedly reflects what's happening in `np.cov()`:

   ```
   X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44]) 
   X = X0 - X0.mean(axis=0)
   N = X.shape[1]
   fact = float(N - 1)
   C = np.dot(X, X.T) / fact
   ```
8. NumPy code to obtain covariance using `np.linalg.svd()` according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479918/trying-to-check-cov-matrix-calculation-from-svd-using-numpy):

   ```
   X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44]) 
   U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(X0, full_matrices = 0)
   D = np.dot(np.dot(V,np.diag(s**2)),V.T)
   Dadjust = D / (X0.shape[0] - 1)
   print (Dadjust)
   ```

Comment: People speak different language, and different software have different default setting and syntax. Why that is a problem? And could you elaborate your question? Are you asking why there are "inconsistencies" among software?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! @hxd1011, I'm not sure this is a *problem*, per se, but it would be useful to know why two superficially-similar programs do different things. Some of these might be technical (row vs. columns) and others appear to be related to the underlying math, but if you don't know, it can definitely be confusing.

Comment: `Octave` also gives the same results as `Matlab` with the function `cov(A)`.  To answer your question about the difficulty in implementing the function into `Python`, it may be helpful to look at the code the other packages use to make the useful function `cov()`.  As `Octave` and `R` are open source, it is relatively easy to look at the code behind these functions.

Comment: This seems potentially on topic here, potentially not.  I'm not sure. I think this is ambiguous.

Comment: The Rosetta stone for stats are the definitions of covariance, transposition, etc. In each computer language, one needs to check what is being done, for example normalized covariance is a correlation, and non-normalized and scaled covariance would be different.

Comment: (7) and (8) clearly are programming errors: if you would like an explanation, please show details of the calculations.  The rest of the differences are readily understood by referring to the documentation.  The `R` documentation alone has enough information to understand why such differences would crop up and even to predict them quantitatively.

Comment: While understanding various software is clearly the hook that motivated this question, understanding different ways to get the covariance, why they might be preferred, & why they might lead to discrepancies, strikes me as on topic. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 11):

Note that `numpy.cov()` considers its input data matrix to have observations in each *column*, and variables in each *row*, so to get `numpy.cov()` to return what other packages do, you have to pass the *transpose* of the data matrix to `numpy.cov()`.

The Python code that you linked can be used to simulate what other packages do, but it contains some errors: `N` should be the number of rows, not columns, and you have to perform the matrix multiplication in the other order:

```
import numpy as np

def cov(X0):
    print "\n==\nMatrix:"
    print X0
    X = X0 - X0.mean(axis=0)
    N = X.shape[0]                # !!!
    fact = float(N - 1)
    print "Covariance:"
    print np.dot(X.T, X) / fact   # !!!

X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4]))
cov(X0)
cov(X0.T)

X0 = np.vstack(([1, 2], [3, 4], [22, 44]))
cov(X0)
cov(X0.T)
```

With these fixes, the covariance behaves as expected:

```
==
Matrix:
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
Covariance:
[[ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]]

==
Matrix:
[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
Covariance:
[[ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]]

==
Matrix:
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [22 44]]
Covariance:
[[ 134.33333333  274.33333333]
 [ 274.33333333  561.33333333]]

==
Matrix:
[[ 1  3 22]
 [ 2  4 44]]
Covariance:
[[   0.5    0.5   11. ]
 [   0.5    0.5   11. ]
 [  11.    11.   242. ]]
```

As for the `numpy.linalg.svd()` code, you need to *center* the data matrix by subtracting off the variable means, and the multiplication involving the V matrix must be performed in the other order. With these changes you will replicate everybody else's behavior:

```
import numpy as np

def cov(X0):
    print "\n==\nMatrix:"
    print X0
    X = X0 - X0.mean(axis=0)
    U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices = 0)
    D = np.dot(np.dot(V.T,np.diag(s**2)),V)
    Dadjust = D / (X0.shape[0] - 1)
    print "Covariance:"
    print (Dadjust)
```

Comment: Key difference between np.cov() and the corresponding cov() methods in Matlab, R and Pandas is, as you say, NumPy cov() considers rows to be observations instead of columns. You are right, thank you. I hope we'll get an answer shedding light on why SciKit Learn's Empirical Covariance method returns different values or why the SVD likewise fails to produce the results promised by the post I linked to.

Comment: @JohnStrong I haven't looked at the SVD approach, but the reason why SciKit Learn returns a different result is that the Empirical Covariance is dividing by N instead of N-1. You'll get everybody else's covariance if you multiply the output from sklearn by $N/(N-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up what the empirical variance routine is doing, grand_chat!!

Comment: Just noticed the follow-up explaining what I was missing with regard to the little SVD algorithm. Very much appreciated. Thanks for taking time.